# param is missing or the value is empty for:

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a POST request from an api

I do not want to save anything in my application,
i would just like to send a request to the data and get an ok

**my script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var value = $('#form').serialize()

console.log(value);
$.ajax({
    url : 'https://1broker.com/api/v1/order/create.php?',
    type: 'post',
    dataType : 'html',
    data: value,
    beforeSend : function(){
        $('.load').show('100');
    },
    success : function(pre){
        $('.load').hide('100');
    }
   });
  });
 </script>
```

**here is my controller**

```
private

def set_position
  @position = Position.find(params[:id])
end


def position_params
  params.require(:position).permit(:symbol, :margin, :direction, :leverage, :order_type, :referral_id).permit(nil)
end
```

end

**and the form**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form" method="post">
      <select class="form-control" name="symbol">
        <option> </option>
        <option>USDJPY</option>
        <option>EURUSD</option>
      </select>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="margin">
      <select class="form-control" name="direction">
        <option> </option>
        <option>long</option>
        <option>short</option>
      </select>
      <input class="form-control" name="leverage">
      <input type="hidden" name="order_type" value="market">
      <input type="hidden" name="referral_id" value="9918">
      <input class="form-control" name="stop_loss">
      <input class="form-control" name="take_profit">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
  </form>
```

**in applicationController i'm using**

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that your ajax call doesn't match what your strong params are searching for.

```
  $.ajax({
    url : 'https://1broker.com/api/v1/order/create.php?',
    type: 'post',
    dataType : 'html',
    data: value,
    beforeSend : function(){
      $('.load').show('100');
    },
    success : function(pre){
     $('.load').hide('100');
    }
  });


  def position_params
    params.require(:position).permit(:symbol, :margin, :direction,:leverage, :order_type, :referral_id).permit(nil)
  end
```

You could either change your ajax call like Gokul M said

```
  data: { position: value }
```

or you could modify your strong params to not require position if you don't need to for other actions:

```
  def position_params
    params.permit(:symbol, :margin, :direction,:leverage, :order_type, :referral_id).permit(nil)
  end
```

Comment: I don't understand. It didn't create a new order in the database? Or it didn't show up on your site after the Ajax call?

Comment: it did not create the order on the site where I'm using the api : https://1broker.com/api/v1......

Comment: I don't know if there's more javascript not here, but you'll have to append it to the html on your page upon success. To see if it's even returning you could put a debugger in your success and check if the object is there and correct. If it is which I believe it should be if it's succeeding you then need to  use something like.  `$( ".foo" ).append( "<p>" + pre.margin + "</p>" );` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `data: value` to `data: {position: value}` in your **ajax** call.

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'https://1broker.com/api/v1/order/create.php?',
    type: 'post',
    dataType : 'html',
    data: {position: value},
    beforeSend : function(){
        $('.load').show('100');
    },
    success : function(pre){
        $('.load').hide('100');
    }
   });
  });
```